# is it possible to form a list of keys from dictionary values? if not, is there an easier method to solve this?

Tags: python-2.7

The question is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfKb4.jpg) as I can't upload images yet. Basically I've tried to do some code, but I got stuck :/
I'm not sure if I can call dictionary keys by value? I heard somewhere that I can't, but I need to form a list of ([key,key,key...], common value).

This was what I coded so far, is my approach correct?

```
import collections

def meh(n):
    c=n.split()
    count= collections.Counter(c)
#    l=sorted(zip(*count)[1])
    for k, value in count.iteritems():
        return k, value
#        if v =  max(list(v)):
#            return sorted(list(k)), max(v)
```

The comment hashes are because I tried different methods which also didn't work out for me ><"

Comment: Hard to follow. Can you provide example input and output you're trying to achieve?

Comment: the output and all is in the linked image ;A ;;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want to get a list of all the keys in a dictionary. To do this you can use

```
myarray = dictionary.keys()
```

myarray will then be a list of all the keys in the dictionary.

Comment: ahh sorry if my question wasn't clear ><"
i basically from my original question took the string of numbers already and sorted them into a dictionary, so it becomes such that each entry is number: number of occurrences.
what my question wants me to do is that i need to find which numbers in the original string has the highest number of occurrences, then output it as a tuple like this: ([list of number(s) with highest occurrence), times it occurred).

Comment: the reason i asked if could get the keys from a value in itself was because when i did collections.Counter() it gave me a dictionary, and i was wondering if i could move from there.